# Django gunicorn Can't connect to socket as user

Tags: python, django, sockets, gunicorn

Gunicorn shows me socket failed to connect when run as user, but when run as root it worked flawlessly. Below is the command.

```
cd /home/myuser/web/myproject 

source /home/myuser/myvenv/bin/activate

/home/myuser/myvenv/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --name myproject --workers 3 --user=myuser --group=www-data --bind=unix:/home/myuser/myvenv/run/gunicorn.sock
```

where

- Django project path: `/home/myuser/web/myproject` (which contains manage.py)
- Python virtualenv path: `/home/myuser/myvenv`

When run as root:

```
[2017-12-27 23:25:43 +0000] [24336] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-12-27 23:25:43 +0000] [24336] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/myuser/myvenv/run/gunicorn.sock (24336)
[2017-12-27 23:25:43 +0000] [24336] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-12-27 23:25:43 +0000] [24339] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24339
[2017-12-27 23:25:43 +0000] [24340] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24340
[2017-12-27 23:25:44 +0000] [24377] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24377
```

I killed the process, and made sure it does not exist in `ps -A | grep gunicorn`. Then I tried to run same command as `myuser`. Below is the error when I run the command.

```
[2017-12-27 23:21:30 +0000] [23965] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2017-12-27 23:21:30 +0000] [23965] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-12-27 23:21:31 +0000] [23965] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-12-27 23:21:32 +0000] [23965] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-12-27 23:21:33 +0000] [23965] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-12-27 23:21:34 +0000] [23965] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2017-12-27 23:21:35 +0000] [23965] [ERROR] Can't connect to 
/home/myuser/myvenv/run/gunicorn.sock
```

Things I have done:

- Installed all dependencies.
- Made sure all folders exists with correct permission to `myuser`.
- `chmod 777` to both Django project and Python virtualenv path.
- `chown myuser:www-data` to both Django project and Python virtualenv path.
- used other path than `/home/myuser/myvenv/run/gunicorn.sock` like `/home/myuser/myvenv/run/myproject.sock` or `/home/myuser/myvenv/socket/gunicorn.sock` 
  `/tmp/gunicorn.sock` in gunicorn's bind parameter.

Comment: Update: I can run Gunicorn by appending *sudo* in front of the script. Any idea? *sudo* /home/myuser/myvenv/bin/gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application --name myproject --workers 3 --user=myuser --group=www-data --bind=unix:/home/myuser/myvenv/run/gunicorn.sock

Comment: What happens if you disable selinux?